# No ringtone for Face Time

Tags: ipad

I don't get a ring tone when I get a face time call. In addition when i charge the iPad I used to get a ting sound. Now I don't get that either. Are both the problems connected?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably in the [Silent mode](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204171). Try to put side switch in the initial state. Here is the picture of the side switch location:

[image: iPad side switch]

Comment: Thank you "alljamin"! That did the trick. Very grateful to you

Comment: Great to hear that! If my answer solved your problem then please accept it. Here is how you can accept it http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/319051.